# How to access MP3 tag information

Tags: iphone

I am using the AVAudioPlayer to play songs in my app.  I would like to display the Artist name and song name.  Is there anyway of accessing this information from the ID3 tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below links

[reading MP3 ID tags](http://www.iphonedevbook.com/forum/iphone-development-questions/805-reading-mp3-id-tags.htmlc)

[Get album artwork from MP3 file/ID3 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907164/get-album-artwork-from-mp3-file-id3-tag)

[Reading MP3 information using objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239460/reading-mp3-information-using-objective-c)