# Getting name of track that is currently being played

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

Is there a way to get the name of the track that is currently being played in iTunes on an iOS device?

I haven't found anything too useful in`MPMusicPlayerController` nor `AVAudioPlayer`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, after some more searching, I found the answer hidden in this semi-related question: [Get album artwork from MP3 file/ID3 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907164/get-album-artwork-from-mp3-file-id3-tag)

There are two properties that exist in `MPMusicPlayerController` that provides us with the Track Name and Track Artist. They are `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle` and `MPMediaItemPropertyArtist`, respectively.

Comment: Have to wait for 22 more hours - found the answer couple hours after posting the question. Glad to hear it works! =p

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer's answer contains 5x the code you need to get what you're after. Here's a simpler answer:

```
if ([MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer].playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
    MPMediaItem *item = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
    NSString *title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString *artist = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]; // common
    // do something with these
} else {
    // nothing is playing!
}
```